# Get the Project hierarchy using the workspace reference

Tags: java, rest, rally

i'm trying to fetch the list of project  with the children / hierarchy and input passed is workspace reference. i have tried the below code for that

```
GetRequest discussionRequest = new GetRequest(workspaceReference);
Fetch fetch = new Fetch("Projects");
GetResponse discussionResponse = rallyClient.get(discussionRequest);
discussionRequest.setFetch(fetch);
```

But this is giving all the project but not the hierarchy details.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Parent project, use the following code

```
QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest("Projects");
queryRequest.setWorkspace(workspace);
queryRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("Parent", "=", "null"));
QueryResponse queryResponse = rallyClient.query(queryRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons there is not a way to retrieve full hierarchies of objects all at once through Rally's WSAPI.  You can do one of two things: either fetch Parent and then stitch the data together yourself or manually recursively walk the tree fetching Children.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, how to get only the parent projects with the workspace reference

Comment: Hi Kyle, using the above code, i'm getting all the projects in the workspace, there is no reference for the parent project. Do i need to filter anything to get the 1st level project

Comment: I forgot that unless you are a workspace admin (or otherwise have read access to every project in the hierarchy) you will likely miss data to stitch the hierarchy back together.  In this case it sounds like you may not have access to any of the root level projects...